# No puedo cerrar mi Modal

Tags: javascript, html

Éste es mi Modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">        
    <span class="close" id="btnCerrar" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="C_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false">
            <div id="Entrega_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" class="carousel-inner">
                <!-- IMAGENES -->
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simplemente lo que me pasa es que hago click sobre la 'X' para cerrar el modal y no lo hace. Eh intentado con funciones en Javascript y nada.

```
function CloseModal() {
   let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    modal.style.display = "none";
    //modal.remove();
}

function CierraPopup() {
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
}
```

No lo esconde, y no puedo usar el `modal.remove()` porque sino no vuelve a abrir.

O tambien en vez del `<span>` tener un  `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>`.

Ni tampoco el que me da de ejemplo Bootstrap 5:

```
<div class="modal-header">      
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
```

De paso les muestro cómo se ve si uso un `<button>`, que se ve un rectangulo gris, pero si ubico el mouse por encima de éste, se activa el `hover` del boton y se puede ver

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cómo se ve cuando uso `<span>`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaración: es un `carousel modal`

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="CloseModal(@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega())" aria-label="Close"></button>

function CloseModal(entrega) {
    let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    let carouselItem = document.getElementById('Entrega_' + entrega)
    while (carouselItem.firstChild) {
        carouselItem.removeChild(carouselItem.firstChild)
    }
    modal.style.display = "none";    
}
```

Basicamente lo que hice fue ponerle el atributo `onclick` al boton de cerrar con la funcion `CloseModal()`, luego dentro de `CloseModal()` obtengo el <div id="Entrega_"...> que dentro de éste estan todos los `item-carousel` (las imagenes). Y bueno, mientras que `carouselItem` tenga un hijo, voy eliminandolos.